# Developing API from ARKit

Tags: arkit

I just started developing using Apple's new ARKit.  If I develop a useful app using the kit, is it possible to develop the app into an API?

Comment: ARKit it's the framework. Of course, you can make a wrapper: an API which is based on it. The difference is that minimum iOS version is going to be iOS 11. Plus ARKit requires A9 compatible devices: and , of course, simulator doesn't support AR.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, exposing your app somehow on a web server, it probably won't be possible, ARKit uses the sensors on your phone in order to calculate your position in the virtual/real space.

In any case, you might want to refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your question is to develop some APIs based on ARKit framework.

If I'm getting the question right, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit is completely native. It will run only on iOS devices ( iOS >=11 & (iPhone6s & later) ), as it is bundled with the iOS operating system.

It is just like UIKit or any other Kit comes with iOS.

Of course, you can combine **APIs** & **ARKit** to make powerful apps..just like **IKEA** ( furniture catalog * ARKit) and **POKEMON Go** ( Location Services & ARKit)